# Como listar de dos modelos relacionados

Tags: python, django, django-views

Tengo estos dos modelos

```
class Comunidad(models.Model):
    rut = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=70)

     def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rut)

     class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'comunidad'

class Asiste(models.Model):
    id_capacitacion = models.ForeignKey('Capacitacion', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_capacitacion', primary_key=True)
    rut = models.ForeignKey('Comunidad', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='rut')
    fecha = models.DateField()

     class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'asiste'
        unique_together = (('id_capacitacion', 'rut'),)
```

Y en un `ListView` quiero listar todo de asiste en este caso la id el rut y le fecha pero ademas quiero al lado me aparezca el nombre asociado al rut que obviamente este nombre lo encuentro en mi modelo 'Comunidad', esta es mi `ListView`.

```
class persona_lista(ListView):
    model = Asiste
    template_name = 'asistencia.html'
```

Y mi template estaría de esta manera:

```
 {% for persona in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{persona.id_capacitacion }}</th>
        <td>{{persona.rut }}</td>
        <td>{{persona.fecha }}</td>
    </tr>
 {%endfor%}
```

No se como agregar la columna del nombre asociado al rut, rut seria el id de cada persona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer esta documentación de [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/relations/) que se trata de relacionar modelos.

Para tu caso sería algo como así:

```
class Comunidad(models.Model):
   pass

class Asiste(..):
   rut = Comunidad()
```

Entonces, dado el objeto, harías:

```
c = Comunidad.objects.all()
a = c.asiste_set.all()
```

El `_set` objeto está disponible cuando [related_nameno se especifica](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)